# Laravel8 Route [upload] not defined

Tags: laravel

```
Route::prefix('admin')->middleware(['auth'])->group(function(){
Route::view('upload', 'upload');
});
```

My view page is inside an "admin" folder in views, so this is why I used the prefix. It still doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

Take look at [View Routes Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#view-routes)

**For example:**

```
Route::view('/welcome', 'welcome');
```

First param is route path and second is view path.

When you are using `Route::prefix('admin')`, prefix affects only url path, not view path.

So you have to specify full view path no matter if route has prefix or not.
So your code should be like this:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->middleware(['auth'])->group(function(){
   Route::view('upload', 'admin.upload');
});
```

And `admin.upload` will be accessed at `/admin/upload` path